# Is there a way to have 2 different Inject ID in the same script?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, zenject

I'm working on a card game in which both you and the opponent use mana, because of that i created a ManaManager class and bind it using the WithId method.

```
public override void InstallBindings()
    {
        // Bind ManaManager for Team.Ally
        Container.Bind<ManaManager>().WithId(Team.Ally).AsSingle();

        // Bind ManaManager for Team.Enemy
        Container.Bind<ManaManager>().WithId(Team.Enemy).AsSingle();
    }
```

The issue comes when i want to create a script to display the mana, i would love to have 1 class called ManaGraphics that handles all the UI for mana, but i dont know how to or if its even posible to change the Inject Id without creating a subclass.

```
[Inject]
    public void Constructor([Inject(Id = Team.Ally)] ManaManager manaManager)
    {
        _manaManager = manaManager;
    }
```

For now i created a class named AllyManaGraphics that handles the dependency injection but i dont feel like this is the right solution, i cannot put the graphics handling part on the ManaManager class since i dont need the enemy to have this kind of UI right now.

Is there something im missing?

Answer (score 0):

You have to look at `GameObjectContext` class. If player and the enemy are different gameObjects as they should be, then each of them has their own context of dependencies. So you don't have to inject both managers in a Scene or Project context with different Id's, you have to inject ManaManager without id's in `GameObjectContext` of each entities instead.

Then you have to solve how you wish to display values for both of them. And it really depends on how did you implement UI. If you have some kind of general UIManager in main context, then you can pass ManaManager instance to UIManager as a parameter via OnInstantiate method in Installer class. Something like that:

```cs
Container.Bind<ManaManager>().OnInstantiated<ManagManager>((_context,_object) =>
 _context.Container.Resolve<UIManager>().Setup(_object, SomeEnum.Player)
);
```

It's just an demonstration example. In your concrette situation it may differs.